# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'computation'

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, keras

Im trying to use Keras (Sequential) but I get the following error when I try to import it:

```
File "kaggle_titanic_keras.py", line 3, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import applications
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .vgg16 import VGG16
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/applications/vgg16.py", line 14, in <module>
    from ..models import Model
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import layers as layer_module
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..engine import Layer
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .training import Model
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .. import callbacks as cbks
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.tensorboard.plugins import projector
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import factorization
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops.gmm import *
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/__init__.py", line 297, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 31, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in <module>
    import dask.dataframe as dd
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 38, in <module>
    pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'computation'
```

Im running Python 2.7, TensorFlow 1.1 , Keras 2.0.3 and 'upgraded' to Pandas 0.20.1 yesterday which I suspect is causing the problem but the error message says nothing about it.

Comment: how did you update `pandas` ? are you sure that your python from anaconda can access it ?

Comment: I did used conda and pip.  I just used .__version__ to check the pandas version it was accessing and it came back with 0.20.1

Comment: This is due to the new release of pandas (0.20.1). A new release of dask came out on Friday to fix things that broke in the new pandas release. Updating dask to 0.14.3 should fix your error.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

## Update dask to 0.15.0 will solve the issue

update cmd: `conda update dask`

input `pip show dask` will show follow message

```
Name: dask
Version: 0.15.0
Summary: Parallel PyData with Task Scheduling
Home-page: http://github.com/dask/dask/
Author: Matthew Rocklin
Author-email: mrocklin@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages
Requires:
```

Comment: Updating dask worked for me. However I updated it through pip rather than conda:

    pip install --upgrade dask

Comment: Need to update dask to > 0.15.3 according to [pandas issue 18355](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18355#issuecomment-345453318)

Answer (score 18):

dask-0.14.3 works and eliminates the import error

Answer (score 11):

I reverted back to Pandas 0.19.2 and it resolved this problem.

Comment: I think the better answer is to update dask as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44615129/1863542

Answer (score 9):

The full command I use is

```
conda install pandas=0.19.2
```

and answer y to downgrade the pandas and it worked now.

Answer (score 5):

I had installed below versions:

- python 3.5
- tensorflow 1.2.1
- pandas 0.21
- dask 0.15.3

and was getting the following error:

```
pd.core.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'expressions'
```

I downgraded to ***pandas 0.19.2*** and ***dask 0.15.0*** and the python script worked fine!