# Tensorflow Object Detection API installation error 'AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation''

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the install instructions for the TF Object Detection API [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md). However the final step is to test the install with:

`python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py`

It fails with error:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

Any ideas?
The path is correctly set as specified and I'm running from within the models folder.
I'm using the AWS Deep Learning AMI and pandas does exist.

Full stack trace:

> (root) ubuntu@ip-172-31-34-128:~/models$ python object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "object_detection/builders/model_builder_test.py", line 21, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import model_builder
>     File "/home/ubuntu/models/object_detection/builders/model_builder.py", line 19, in 
>       from object_detection.builders import box_predictor_builder
>     File "/home/ubuntu/models/object_detection/builders/box_predictor_builder.py", line 18, in 
>       from object_detection.core import box_predictor
>     File "/home/ubuntu/models/object_detection/core/box_predictor.py", line 35, in 
>       slim = tf.contrib.slim
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 53, in **getattr**
>       module = self._load()
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 42, in _load
>       module = importlib.import_module(self.**name**)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/**init**.py", line 31, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib import factorization
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/**init**.py", line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.factorization.python.ops.gmm import *
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/factorization/python/ops/gmm.py", line 27, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/**init**.py", line 88, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/**init**.py", line 23, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/**init**.py", line 25, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import estimators
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/**init**.py", line 297, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators.dnn import DNNClassifier
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py", line 30, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import dnn_linear_combined
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn_linear_combined.py", line 31, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import estimator
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py", line 49, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io import data_feeder
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/**init**.py", line 21, in 
>       from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.learn_io.dask_io import extract_dask_data
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/learn_io/dask_io.py", line 26, in 
>       import dask.dataframe as dd
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
>     File "/home/ubuntu/src/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 36, in 
>       pd.computation.expressions.set_use_numexpr(False)
>   AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'computation'

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, I suggest using the following command in your terminal/cmd: 
`conda update dask`

Alternatively you can use the following command to change the version of your `pandas`, although I suggest the first solution:
`conda install pandas=0.19.2` 
For more information take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833081/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-computation).