# No module named 'pandas.core.computation.expressions'

Tags: pandas

I've never encountered this error before, but after I redownload python packages, I got this error.

I'm doing a calculation of a list of time difference as follows:

```
df = (A - B)
```

where A and B are pandas.core.series format and I received this error:

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py in new_method(self, other)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in wrapper(left, right)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_arithmetic_op(left, right, op, str_rep)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.core.computation.expressions'
```

I tried redownloading and updating pandas but it doesn't work

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833081/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-computation

Comment: I have the same issue